# Function to find filenames containing a string

Tags: command-line, bash, functions

I am trying to create this function, but I don't find the correct syntax:

```
function contains {
    find . -maxdepth 1 -i -name *$1*
}
```

The aim is to type `contains xxx` to get the list of files containing `xxx` in their names.

Comment: Considered to use `locate`?

Comment: What's `-i` supposed to do? `function contains { find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*$1*" ; }` works.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the filename contains `xxx` or, within the file the text `xxx` exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice function :) Assuming you want `i` to indicate a case-insensitive search, one way could be

```
contains() {
   find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*$1*"
}
```

It's very important to quote `*` when passing to `find`, (as well as your `$1` of course) to avoid it being expanded by the shell, which will cause the command to go very wrong if there are matching filenames in the current directory.

Comment: +1 although in this case (since the intent appears to be exactly to glob-match files in the current directory) it might be more direct to skip the `find` altogether and *allow* the shell to expand the pattern e.g. `contains() { (shopt -s failglob; printf '%s\n' *"$1"* ); }`

Comment: @steeldriver you can just do: `contains() (shopt -s failglob; printf '%s\n' *"$1"* )` - a function body is just a list of commands, and `()` can mark a list just as well as `{}`.

Comment: @steeldriver now do post an answer! :D (Maybe even show them the dotglob and extglob options)

Comment: @steeldriver yeah that's much better! thanks for teaching and +1 to your answer in advance